# How to set value of <select> with value that contains special symbol?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the value of a `<select>` in JQuery, with val() that contains a special symbol. Tried a few different options, but can't get through.
Please help.

```js
$("#newNumOfProv").val("&lt; 5 Providers");
```

```html
<select class="form-control" value="select" id="newNumOfProv">
  <option>Select number of provides</option>
  <option>&lt; 5 Providers</option>
  <option>5-20 Providers</option>
  <option>20-100 Providers</option>
  <option>100-500 Providers</option>
  <option>Over 500 Providers</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you wanna select **only by value** or can you use `index`?

Comment: Value is much easier in my case, as far as I get json with this val.

Comment: Solved. Check it out. Just use the `< 5 Providers` as the value, without escaping.

Answer (score 1):

`&lt;` is an HTML escape sequence.

`.val()` takes a simple string, not HTML, so you should pass the actual `<` character.

Answer (score 0):

Try just using the HTML Version `<`, as `&lt;` is valid only for HTML and not values. See below.

```js
$("#newNumOfProv").val("< 5 Providers");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="form-control" value="select" id="newNumOfProv">
  <option>Select number of provides</option>
  <option>&lt; 5 Providers</option>
  <option>5-20 Providers</option>
  <option>20-100 Providers</option>
  <option>100-500 Providers</option>
  <option>Over 500 Providers</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

So

```
 $("#newNumOfProv").val("< 5 providers");
```

works

but I would prefer this which uses the proper values as you really should set:

```
<select class="form-control" value="select" id="newNumOfProv">
  <option value="">Select number of provides</option>
  <option value"0-4">&lt; 5 Providers</option>
  <option value="5-20">5-20 Providers</option>
  <option value"20-200">20-100 Providers</option>
  <option value="100-500">100-500 Providers</option>
  <option value="100-500">Over 500 Providers</option>
</select>
```

using

```
$("#newNumOfProv").val("0-4");
```

Alternatively

```
$("#newNumOfProv").get(0).selectedIndex=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you must use the html escape sequence then you can put it in a html element and grab the text to get the correct value

```
$("#newNumOfProv").val($("<div>").html("&lt; 5 Providers").text());
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8znfv41c/)